# Uma trigger pode "anular/desfazer" a ação que a dispara?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

#### Cenário exemplo

Tenho uma tabela `telefones` onde tenho uma ***trigger*** que é disparada ao realizar a instrução ***insert***.

---

#### Dúvida

- Posso usar a *trigger* para **verificar uma condição** e diante do retorno, **"cancelar" a ação** na tabela que a disparou?
- Teria como **definir a mensagem de "atenção/erro"** que o *SQL* irá retornar?

(*Um exemplo seria extremamente importante*)

Comment: Sim e Sim mas note que isso é uma má prática por vários motivos. A boa prática é colocar as regras de negócio na camada de regras de negócio e lá decidir se a ação deve ou não ser realizada e dar o devido feedback ao usuário

Comment: @jean Concordo com você, a trigger praticamente sempre será um "remendo". Mas nos casos de sistemas de terceiros que não há possibilidade de alteração no fonte, a trigger acaba salvando! rs

Comment: @JoséDiz tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela descrição que você deu o ideal seria utilizar uma `trigger` do tipo `instead of`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_tabela ON tabela
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF -- Sua condição para o erro aqui
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Mensagem de erro.', 16, 1);
    END
    ELSE -- Insere 
    BEGIN
        INSERT tabela
        SELECT i.*
          FROM inserted i;
    END;
END;
GO
```

No caso do exemplo não executável acima a inserção somente será realizada na tabela caso a condição do `IF` não seja satisfeita.

---

> `INSTEAD OF`
>
> Especifica que o gatilho DML será executado em vez da instrução SQL de gatilho, substituindo as ações das instruções de gatilho. INSTEAD OF não pode ser especificado para gatilhos DDL ou de logon.
>
> No máximo, um gatilho INSTEAD OF por instrução INSERT, UPDATE ou DELETE pode ser definido em uma tabela ou exibição. Entretanto, você pode definir exibições sobre exibições, onde cada uma tem seu próprio gatilho INSTEAD OF.
>
> Os gatilhos INSTEAD OF não são permitidos em exibições atualizáveis que usam WITH CHECK OPTION. O SQL Server gera um erro quando um gatilho INSTEAD OF é adicionado a uma WITH CHECK OPTION de exibição atualizável especificado. O usuário deve remover essa opção usando ALTER VIEW antes de definir o gatilho INSTEAD OF.

Comment: Muito bom Sorack! Mas essa frase sua me confundiu e me deixou um pouco de dúvida "Pela descrição que você deu o ideal seria utilizar uma trigger do tipo instead of". Então só para extinguir qualquer dúvida mínima: o `instead of` seria o "ideal" ou seria a única forma?

Comment: @rbz No caso que você descreveu acredito que a única forma. Em um cenário onde você pudesse fazer a chamada por uma `procedure` acredito que seria o ideal.